# Why do stream operators return references in C++?

Tags: c++, stream

I know that indexing operator implementations usually return references so that the values can be set as well as retrieved, but why do streams?

Answer (score 12):

So you can chain them together.

```
cout << "hello" << "how are you";
```

Works because `cout << "hello"` returns a reference to the cout so that `<< "how are you"` knows there to put itself.

Most operators, such as `+=`, also do this.

Comment: Addition should definitely return a value, you mean `+=`?

Comment: @Barry Yes I do, but the thought carries through, technically addition returns a value which is also a reference to said value, I'll change it to `+=` though.

Comment: @Dylan `operator+` definitely shouldn't return a reference.

Comment: @remyabel No it returns a value, but in the context of operating chaining, said value plays the same role as a reference does.

Comment: @DylanLawrence: That makes no sense

Comment: "technically addition returns a value which is also a reference to said value." and "in the context of operating chaining, said value plays the same role as a reference does." - @Dylan So why do they return different things?

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn Because when you're dealing with addition you want the object itself. When you're dealing with streams you don't want a copy of the stream device, you simply want a reference to it. `2+3` should return the value 5 as an object. `"Hello " << " World"` returns a reference "pointing" to the streaming object so we can use it again. It's a subtle difference and externally behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

Streams do not support copying or assignment, so anything that passes or returns a stream *must* use either a pointer or reference. You can't use overloaded operators on a pointer (without dereferencing it) because they'd try to apply the built-in operator to the pointer itself.

So, returning a reference is the only choice that supports operator chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Streams don't support copying or assignment because they have no abiding state. By their very nature the data passed into them is merely buffered rather than retained. The whole point of a stream is to flush its contents into something else while blocking program execution on the receiving end when it's empty.